# Scrapy: How to select head and body tags together

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

So, I have a crawler which need to extract some data from meta tags in the head and some element tags in the body.

When I try this

> for courses in response.xpath("//html"):

and this

> for courses in response.xpath("//head"):

it only fetches data from meta tags in the `<head>... </head>` tag.

when I try this

> for courses in response.xpath("//body"):

it only fetch data from tags within the html `<body>... </body>` tag.

How do I combine these 2 selectors, I also tried

> for courses in response.xpath("//head | //body"):

but it only returned 'meta' tags from `<head>... </head>`, nothing was extracted from body.

I also tried this

> for courses in response.xpath("//*"):

it works, But this is highly inefficient and takes a lot of time to extract. I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

**And here is Scrapy code, if it helps ...**

The first 2 elements (pagetype, pagefeatured) under **yeild** are in `<head> ... <head>` tag. The last 2 elements (coursetloc, coursetfees) are in `<body ... </body>` tag

**And Yes, it may look odd, but there are 'meta' tags inside `<body>...</body>` in the website from where I am scraping.**

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dkcourses"
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/scrapy/all-courses-listing']
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
def parse(self, response):
 hxs = Selector(response)
 for courses in response.xpath("//body"):
 yield {
            'pagetype': ''.join(courses.xpath('.//meta[@name="dkpagetype"]/@content').extract()),
            'pagefeatured': ''.join(courses.xpath('.//meta[@name="dkpagefeatured"]/@content').extract()),
            'coursetloc': ''.join(courses.xpath('.//meta[@name="dkcoursetloc"]/@content').extract()),
            'coursetfees': ''.join(courses.xpath('.//meta[@name="dkcoursetfees"]/@content').extract()),
           }
 for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract()):
  yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: post url or html code

Comment: @宏杰李 Posted the code ...

Comment: I mean the website url

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `extract_first()` to get the first value in the `extract()`, do not use `join()`
2. Use `[starts-with(@name, "dkn")]` to find the `meta` tag, `//meta` means in all the content of document.

---

```
In [5]: for meta in response.xpath('//meta[starts-with(@name, "dkn")]'):
   ...:     name = meta.xpath('@name').extract_first()
   ...:     content = meta.xpath('@content').extract_first()
   ...:     print({name:content})
```

out:

```
{'dknpagetype': 'Course'}
{'dknpagefeatured': ''}
{'dknpagedate': '2016-01-01'}
{'dknpagebanner': 'http://www.deakin.edu.au/__data/assets/image/0006/757986/Banner_Cyber-Alt2.jpg'}
{'dknpagethumbsquare': 'http://www.deakin.edu.au/__data/assets/image/0009/757989/SQ_Cyber1-2.jpg'}
{'dknpagethumblandscape': 'http://www.deakin.edu.au/__data/assets/image/0007/757987/LS_Cyber1-1.jpg'}
{'dknpagethumbportrait': 'http://www.deakin.edu.au/__data/assets/image/0008/757988/PT_Cyber1-3.jpg'}
{'dknpagetitle': 'Graduate Diploma of Cyber Security'}
{'dknpageurl': 'http://www.deakin.edu.au/course/graduate-diploma-cyber-security'}
{'dknpagedescription': "Take your understanding of cyber security to the next level with Deakin's Graduate Diploma of Cyber Security and build your capacity to investigate and combat cyber-crime."}
{'dknpageid': '723503'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to store the values in variables to send the values to Elasticsearch, not just print on screen, like how  you see in my example code above.

Comment: Never mind, All I needed to change in my code is to change this `for courses in response.xpath("//body"):` to `for courses in response.xpath("//meta"):` All good now ....